# Assign a value to a variable [Excel]

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm making a basic inventory list for my place of work and want to make it easier for future inputs and changes. So far I have inputted all of the model numbers for our inventory, and I was wondering how I could assign a price to the model number, so that it automatically fills it into the cell two cells right. I'm also working with around 50 model numbers, so it would be a lengthy function.
Example:
B       E
778740        125.99
778739        120.99
778740

Is there a way that the second "778740" could be automatically filled in? I'm fairly new to excel and I can't find this problem, although I know it is very simple and exists. Even if some one could link me it that would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to research Excel's VLOOKUP() function.

Comment: @Aron It looks like ultimately that is what I will want to use, but I don't know how to apply it because I am adding the values to the same column. Let's say another 20 rows down there is another 778740, how would I have it automatically updated?

Comment: Why is the same model number appearing in the list with the same price?

Comment: OK, so for now I'll assume that you have multiple units of parts that are serialized, so a quantity column is not a viable option. You could create a separate sheet that has just the price for each part number, then have the inventory sheet do its VLOOKUP against that. Also, as a general warning, attempting to use Excel as a relational database may cause problems in the short and long term.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your headers are in row 1, model numbers in column A and prices in column B. You could use the following formula in cell B3 and drag it on down as far as you need. Then what you fill in in column A matches something above, the cell next to it will automatically populate. And otherwise it stays blank, letting you know it is on you to fill it in (though once you do, the formula will no longer be there, so if you later fill in a match above, the magic is gone).

```
=iferror(indirect("B" & (1+match(A3,A$2:A2,0))),"")
```

The match function returns an error if nothing is found, and ifError will handle that by leaving your cell blank. If a match is found, we get the value from the corresponding row in column B.